# Allowing Users to create their own table of data

Tags: grid-layout, user-defined

We want to allow our web users to define a timetable for themselves. However because the events are very varied the information may not be exactly the same so the column headings and number of columns vary. (We may be forced to define it in general terms - so we define the column headings and they enter the data.) They also need to be able to sort and filter. Import from spreadsheet would also be good as would printing or exporting.

We are using PHP & Laravel Framework.
Does anyone know of something that might help us do this quickly and efficiently?

Thank you

Comment: It will help to provide what programming language and/or framework your question is regarding

Comment: PHP & Laravel Framework, amended question

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions?